# node.js scrape html data values from external website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

As it is my first question, first I want to say hello to stackoverflow community :)

I've started to learn node.js recently. I want to scrap currency values from here: https://www.dailyfx.com/forex-rates and then save them in .txt file as exercise.

I found cheerio.js framework and tried it.

HTML code from that page:

```
<tbody>
  <tr id="EURUSD" data-market-id="EURUSD" class="rates-now">
    <td>
      <span title="EURUSD">
        <a href="eur-usd">EURUSD</a>
      </span>
    </td>
    <td class="text-right rates-row-td">
      <span data-symbol="EURUSD" data-type="bid" data-value="1.19016" data-changescale="-1"></span>
    </td>
    <td class="text-right rates-row-td">
      <span data-symbol="EURUSD" data-type="ask" data-value="1.21016" data-changescale="-1"></span>
    </td>
    <td class="text-right rates-row-td">
      <span id="EURUSD-spread">0.60</span>
    </td>
    <td class="text-right rates-row-td">
      <span class="calendar-toggle-btn"></span>
    </td>
</tbody>
```

My node.js code:

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var fs = require('fs');

request("https://www.dailyfx.com/forex-rates", function(error, response, body) {
  if(error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error);
  }
  console.log("Status code: " + response.statusCode);

  var $ = cheerio.load(body);

  $('tr.rates-row').each(function( index ) {
    var title = $(this).attr('data-market-id');
    console.log("Title: " + title);
    var value = $(this).find('td.rates-row-td > span').attr('data-value');
    console.log(" Value= " + value);
    fs.appendFileSync('stara.txt', value + '\n');
  });
});
```

Output is like:

```
Status code: 200
Title: EURUSD
 Value= undefined
Title: USDJPY
 Value= undefined
Title: AUDUSD
 Value= undefined
Title: GBPUSD
 Value= undefined
Title: USDCAD
 Value= undefined
```

and so on. I don't know why values of attribute data-value are undefined.

Comment: you could simply load your data in json format: https://content.dailyfx.com/getData?contenttype=minicalendar&importance=HIGH,MEDIUM&maxresults=6&language=en

Comment: can you explain more please?

Comment: Since I believe that the values are retrieved asyncronously I think you can miss some value, but if you inspect the network tab of your developer tools you can see an ajax call, your values are in that response in json format. All the best

Comment: I believe it's undefined because it's constantly updating the request with jquery.  Also, when calling data values it would look like  var value = $(this).find('.rates-row-td > span').data('value');

Answer (score 0):

The content is being dynamically inserted with javascript.  Cheerio can only read HTML, so it will always be undefined.

You would either need to use something like Puppeteer, jSDom, phantomjs, etc.